# Grouping by month-year after using datetime.strptime

Tags: python, csv, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I'm fairly new at this. I have a csv that has a string date/time column as shown below. I am trying to average flow values based on month-year.

CSV:

```
X                   Flow
6/9/16/ 14:00       15000
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

#import csv
df = pd.read_csv('monthlyaverage.csv', header=True)

date_object = datetime.strptime('6/9/16 14:00', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M')

df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df))

df1 = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='%m/%y')).mean()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and set column `X` to `index` by parameter `'index_col'`. Then first convert `index` to [`DatetimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) and then [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html). Last [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `index` (`level=0`) and aggregate [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""X,Flow
6/9/16/ 14:00,15000
6/9/16/ 14:00,55000
6/9/16/ 14:00,35000"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), index_col='X')

df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index, format='%m/%d/%y %H:%M').to_period('M')
print (df)
          Flow
2016-06  15000
2016-06  55000
2016-06  35000

print (df.groupby(level=0).mean())
          Flow
2016-06  35000
```

Comment: After running it a second time its coming up with no numeric types to aggregate.

Comment: What is `print (df.dtypes)` ?

Comment: Flow    object
dtype: object

Comment: It means that column `Flow` is not converted to `float`, but `types` is `string`.

Comment: You can try convert this column to numeric and find by filtering which values are problematic (values, which are not converted to number are NaN) - use `print (df[pd.to_numeric(df.Flow, errors='coerce').isnull()])`

Comment: 3 of my values were set to ICE (for ice effected). I deleted them and it worked. Thanks for your help!